# Only run with an option if a variable is true in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Sorry, this is difficult to explain. I have a long, piped, etc. command like this:

```
param (
    [alias("r")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [switch]$recurse = $false,
    [...]

$allFiles = Get-ChildItem $folder | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge [DateTime]::Now.AddHours($hoursOld) } |
    ForEach-Object {
[...]
```

And there is another way to run Get-ChildItem, which is with the **-recurse option**. I only know how to write the entire command all over again, but with the "-recurse" option, and wrap both ways in an if/else...

Is there a way to include that -recurse after gci only if the -r (switch command line option, alias for $recurse) is **$True**?

ex:

```
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge [DateTime]::Now.AddHours($hoursOld) } |
    ForEach-Object {
[...]

PS C:\PSScripts> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.18728
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: Check out the automatic variable `$PSBoundParameters` and `about_Splatting`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switches can be `$true` or `$false`. Exclusion is the same as `$false`, and inclusion is the same as `$true`. However, you can override this by being explicit:

```
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse:$recurse | Where-Object ...
```

This takes the value of `$recurse`, and applies it to `-recurse`. So you have `-recurse:$true` when `$recurse` is included, and `-recurse:$false` when it is not.

Comment: The alternative is splatting `@PSBoundParameters`

Comment: Indeed. Problem is it limits your function/script parameters. In this example, if you have something that isn't a `Get-ChildItem` parameter you get an error  `Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'thing'`. For a wrapper function/script though where the same parameters are used, `@PSBoundParameters` is a much neater option.